# How do I get and store a string produced every 2 seconds using readline()

Tags: java, sockets

How do I get and store a string produced every 2 seconds using `readline()`? Socket programming.

**#Receiver**

```
try {
  while (true) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    //payload = br.readLine();
    // payload = String.parseString(br.read(char getdata[],0, 65535));//valueOf(char)
    //br.reset();
    int payload_length = payload.length();
    System.out.println("Message sent from client: " + payload + ":: Length ::" + payload_length);
    if (payload_length == stringLength) {
      // for(int k=0;k>=s;k++){
      System.out.println("String length matching");
      String Query1 = "INSERT INTO RpiBuffer (string) values(?)"; //,(payload);
      pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(Query1);
      // pst1.setInt(1, id);
      pst1.setString(1, payload);
      //pst1.setInt(3,isSend);
      pst1.executeUpdate();
      System.out.println("Query 1 Executed::" + pst1);
      // }
    } else {
      System.out.println("String length not matching");
    }
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    //   bw.write(returnedMessage);
    bw.newLine();
    //  System.out.println("Message replied to client: "+returnedMessage);

    bw.flush();
    check_internet();
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Exception in receive_data())::" + e);
}
```

**#Sender**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
        int portNumber = 3002;
        int StringLength = 22;
        int i=0;
        while(true){    //for(i=0;i<99;i++){
            try {
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
               // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream()));

                String s1="1231231231231231231234",s2="0001110001110001110001",s3="0101010101",s4="1111000011110000111100";

                out.write(s1);System.out.println("send data1 successfully????? ");TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                out.write(s2);System.out.println("send data2 successfully????? ");TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                out.write(s3);System.out.println("send data3 successfully????? ");TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                out.write(s4);System.out.println("send data4 successfully????? ");TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
               /* String userInput;
                while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.println(userInput);
                    System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
                }*/

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
               // System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                    hostName);
                //System.exit(1);
            }       
        }    
    }
}
```

run:

```
initializing program.....rpibuffer.RpiBuffer@7852e922
Server start at port 3002.
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 46 seconds)
```

Comment: destination ip and port no already mentioned in Receiver side

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Instead of using comments please add additional info to the question itself, i.e. [edit] the question. While you're at it please also fix the formatting and add some text about what problems you're facing or what errors you get and what you've done to fix them.

Comment: Sender sending `4 string (i.e s1,s2,s3 and s4)` on `30002 port`  along with some delay and i want to catch each string separately but at receiver side not getting a single string.